# Html - Javascript: text

Tags: javascript, java, forms, text

I have the following text inside a *form* on a jsp page:

```
<td id="seltb71b" style="display: none">
  <input type="text" id="tb73Parametro" name="tb73Parametro" value="${varTb73Parametro}" />
</td>
```

Now, this text doesen't always appear on the page, it appears only when a select is selected. On java side, i have the class Form with all validators and one of them is raised when the text is empty.

```
@UseValidators({

    @UseValidator(value = StringLength.class, args = { "1", "50" }, error = "tb71Validator")
    @UseValidator(value = NotNull.class, error = "tb71Validator")
   })
   public String tb71;
```

The question is: how can i call the form error validator using javascript? (client side). 

 I can't add the error validator on java (server side) because if the text doesen't appear the error is however called and this is no good.  

The validator must rise only when the text appears AND is empty.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Comment: So you either do clientside validation with backup validation on the server, or you submit to the server and you handle the validation there.